# With matplotlib for Python, how to plot a dot in the center of cells that were created with pcolor?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am using `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor` to plot a 2D grid like the following:

```
PL.pcolor(array, cmap = PL.cm.YlOrRd, vmin = 0, vmax = 3)
```

Where `array` is just a simple 2D array. That part works fine. But next I try:

```
PL.hold(True)
PL.scatter(x, y, 'blue')
PL.hold(False)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the coordinates where I want a given dot to be plotted. However, instead of getting plotted in the center of the cells of the grid that is plotted with `pcolor`, the dot gets to the corner of the cells (no matter which cell I choose).

Comment: Can you please share more of your code, so we have a clearer starting point?

Comment: @Abdou Sure thing, but its really simply calling `pcolor` then `scatter`. But yeah, I will update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `meshgrid` to generate the mesh of points. If your sampling x and y are uniform, then just add the separation divided by two in each direction. i.e. if separation is 1, then add 0.5 and subtract one point:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = np.arange(10)
p = np.arange(10)
R,P = np.meshgrid(r,p)
data = np.random.random((10,10))
plt.pcolor(R,P,data)
plt.scatter(R[:-1,:-1]+0.5,P[:-1,:-1]+0.5, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

This is in case you use `tripcolor`:
You can calculate the centroid of your points: `triang.triangles` gives you the three point indexes of each triangle, then you calculate the centroid using those three points. i.e. `centroidX = (x1+x2+x3)/3.; centroidY = (y1+y2+y3)/3.;`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.random.random(10)
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
plt.tripcolor(triang,z)
centroidX = [x[i].sum()/3. for i in triang.triangles]
centroidY = [y[i].sum()/3. for i in triang.triangles]
plt.scatter(centroidX,centroidY, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see how the triangles relate to what I asked. I mean, in my questions, as described, I simply plotted a 2D grid with `pcolor` and wanted the scatterplot dots to be centered within such cells.

Comment: So, then what do you mean in your text: by using `matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor`

Comment: I see what the confusion was. For this problem I was specifically just using `pcolor`, not `tripcolor`. I just carreid it over by mistake to the question. Funny enough, thought, your answer - while not solving my current problem in this question - actually helped a lot with another part of my program were I had to do something related to Voronoy triangulation. So many thanks!

Comment: Alright. Updated with pcolor. Though it requieres uniform sampling, but you can figure out if sampling is not uniform how to deal with it.

Comment: @Pablo That's a nice answer. I would just recommend not to use `mpl` as alias for `pyplot`, since it's almost standard to use this for `matplotlib`. Sticking to `import matplotlib as mpl` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` makes it much more comprehensible for everyone.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the suggestion. answer updated. I've recently migrated from importing everything with %pylab inline in `jupyter`, now I prefer %matplotlib inline and then import `pyplot`.